# React Hooks, state not updating from fetch within useEffect

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch, use-effect, use-state

For my react-app/Express app I am trying to update the component state using the `useEffects` to run once when the component renders. Within `useEffect` I make a fetch to the express server.

```
const Favorites = ({ user }) => {
  const loggedIn = user.loginname === "" ? false : true;
  const [favs, setFavs] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (loggedIn) {
      fetch(`/user/favs/${user.loginname}`)
        .then((resp) => resp.json())
        .then((data) => {
          console.log(data);
          setFavs([...data]);
          console.log(favs);
        });
    }
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="mt-d d-flex justify-content-center">
      {loggedIn ? (
        <FavoritesList favs={favs} />
      ) : (
        <h3 className="my-2">Please login to use this feature</h3>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};
```

I make a fetch call on line 11 and am able to print the results on line 14. I then try to update the
component state using `setFavs`. My issue is that the state seems to not be updated or maybe
there is some async issue.

```
const FavoritesList = ({ favs, prop }) => {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(favs);
    // favs.forEach(item => console.log(item))
  }, []);

  return <h5>Dummy component</h5>;
};
```

When I try to print favs on line 16 or print favs within the child(FavoritesList) component it is being passed down to, I get an empty array.

Answer (score 1):

> When I try to print favs on line 16 or print favs within the child(FavoritesList) component it is being passed down to, I get an empty array.

You're right, it is an async issue: your call to `setFavs` is async and `favs` is not yet set on line 16. Calling `setFavs` will cause your UI to re-render, eventually.

You won't see it in your other `useEffect` on line 35, either, because that `useEffect` hook also only runs on first render (`[]`), so that value is not there yet on first render. To see all updates to `favs`, try adding it to the dependencies array (like `[favs]`) or remove the dependencies array altogether.

Answer (score 0):

Change your `useEffect` on the **FavoritesList** to:

```
useEffect(() => {
console.log(favs)
}, [favs])
```

That way the `useEffect` will watch for any changes in the `favs` props. Using an empty array means that the `useEffect` will only trigger in the first render of the functional component. Meaning that it will not be triggered in any of the props change.

Answer (score 0):

I think above two answers made everyhing clean, here is your lifecycle;

```
1 -> Favorites component initialized and rendered (state favs = [empty])
2 -> FavoritesList component initialized and rendered (prop favs = [empty])
3 -> FavoritesList useEffect called (console.log(favs) => [empty array])
4 -> Favorites useEffect called (state favs = [now has data])
5 -> FavoritesList component props is updated (prop favs = [has data]

(prop is updated but you didnt call console.log again, after update)
```

As you can see **FavoritesList** useEffect called before **Favorites** useEffect so it called when favs has no data.
So if you add favs prop to array in useEffect in FavoritesList component, you will have one more step;

```
6 -> FavoritesList useEffect called again (console.log(favs) => [has data])
```

Because useEffect looks for that arrays elements and if one the elements changed it will triger itself again.

Here is your code with working example: [codesandbox.io](https://codesandbox.io/s/romantic-edison-f8kt1?file=/src/Example.js)